# How to find year in a text using Spacy NER?

Tags: machine-learning, python, named-entity-recognition

**Sample Sentence:**

```
1. We originally formed in October 2002 as company and later we established in California in 2004.

2. ABC pvt. ltd. was incorporated in 1988 in Colarado.

3. Since our inception in 1900, we worked hard and turned into a million dollar company in 1920.
```

Now I want to find the year founded in each sentence. i.e., **1. 2002, 2. 1988, 3. 1900**.

I would like to achieve this using NER model. Previously, I've  trained a model using Spacy NER where I annotated only the years(1. 2002, 2. 1988, 3. 1900), but the model did not extract the year in any sentence.

```
content_block, content_block_lower = cleaned_content, cleaned_content.lower()
attributes_values = dict(zip(attr_Lst,[dataframe_rows[attributes] for attributes in attr_Lst]))
 for attribute_key, attribute_values in attributes_values.iteritems():    
if(attribute_key == "Year_Founded"):

        try:
            content_index = content_block_lower.find(str(int(attribute_values)))
            #print content_index
            if(content_index!=-1):
                #print content_block [content_index : content_index+len(str(final_converted_date))+1]
                entity_lst.append((content_index,content_index+len(str(attribute_values)),attribute_key))
        except:
            pass
```

Is there any better way to annotate the year and achieve my desired result?

Comment: Normally dates are one the easiest types of NEs to catch with NER. I don't know Spacy NER but probably there's something to do to configure it? Otherwise I would try a good old pattern matching, years are quite easy: 4 consecutive digits preceded by only a few possible combinations of words: "in" or "in <month>" or "on the xxth <month>" . Btw just the 4 consecutive digits pattern on its own should give you a quite high accuracy, maybe a few false positives here or there.